# How to use a jQuery Plugin Parameter Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm attempting to build a fairly basic jQuery plugin (mostly for learning reasons) and I haven't had an error until I added the `limit` method, which seems pretty straight forward, however I get the following error in the console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: limit is not defined

It's applying to the second if method below (marked with comment)

```
$.fn.query = function(params) {

    // Parameters //
    var options = $.extend({
        'shuffle' : false,
          'limit' : undefined
    }, params),
        output = this;

    // Shuffle //
    if (shuffle) {
        output = shuffle(this);
    }

    // Limit // !!!ERROR!!! //
    if (limit !== undefined) {
        output = output.slice(0, limit);
    }

    return output;
};
```

Then running the plugin

```
var query = $(example).query({
    shuffle: true,
    limit: 5
});
```

I was trying to follow all of the best practices but if you notice anything odd at all please let me know.

Here is a jsFiddle with all of the code, you can see the error in the console.

> http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/CfXhw/

Comment: Try `console.log` on `shuffle`, and I bet you good money it's not the `shuffle` you think it is.

Comment: @adeneo Shuffle has been working fine. Without the limit method it works fine, this shuffle is based on another persons work

Comment: It is not working fine, `shuffle` is part of the `options` object and is accessed with `options.shuffle`, just like `options.limit` would be! On the other hand shuffle is also a function, so your if statement would always be true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `options.` in front of limit.

```
options.limit
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/UWDsz/

You're creating an object, so in order to access it you use the object and variable name split by a period `object.variable`

Corrected jQuery code:

```
$.fn.query = function(params) {

    // Parameters //
    var options = $.extend({
        'shuffle' : false,
          'limit' : undefined
    }, params),
        output = this;

    // Shuffle //
    if (options.shuffle) {
        output = shuffle(this);
    }

    // Limit // !!!ERROR!!! //
    if (options.limit !== undefined) {
        output = output.slice(0, options.limit);
    }

    return output;
};
```

Comment: Is that how it is supposed to be done? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: That's the way you have to do :) You put the two parameters in the options variable so you have to access by that way :)

Comment: You also need to add `options.` before using `shuffle`. The variable `shuffle` does not exist in this context but `options.shuffle` does.